# migration .Net Framework 4.8 to .Net Core 6 - Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: .net-core, migration, owin, identityserver3, asp.net-core-6.0

I just migrated My project from the .net framework 4.8 to the .Net core 6
My Projects have a lot of dependencies like Owin, IdentityServer3, and ...

Finally, my solution builds successfully now, but when I start that I ran to this error :

*Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0...*

Assuming that I can't migrate the identityServer3 and as a result, I can't update any of the Owin packages, ([the Owin(s) version should be less than 4](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/374)), **is there a chance to embed the System.IdentityModel into the .Net 6 web projects?**

[image]

the csproj file :

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BrockAllen.MembershipReboot" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="BrockAllen.MembershipReboot.Ef" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="EasyNetQ" Version="6.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="EasyNetQ.DI.Ninject" Version="6.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="10.3.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="1.9.2" />    
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer3" Version="2.6.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation" Version="2.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="loggly-csharp" Version="4.6.1.76" />
    <PackageReference Include="loggly-csharp-config" Version="4.6.1.76" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" Version="3.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions" Version="1.0.2.206221351" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" Version="4.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Owin" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Hosting" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes" Version="16.11.230815" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy.Bootstrappers.Ninject" Version="1.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy.MSOwinSecurity" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy.Owin" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy.Validation.FluentValidation" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NEventStore" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ninject" Version="3.3.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ninject.Extensions.ChildKernel" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Owin" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OwinHost" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RabbitMQ.Client" Version="6.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="RavenDB.Client" Version="5.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Loggly" Version="5.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching" Version="2.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="4.0.2.206221351" />
    <PackageReference Include="Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.ScopeValidation" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.IdentityModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Caching" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? Were you able to authenticate your migrated application with .net 6? If so, please share it.